# How to be notified of each task run in grunt?

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

I'm using grunt in a phonegap app.
When building my webapp, I'm generating for android, ios and web mobile platform.
So every time I declare a task, generally, I have 3 targets, one per platform.

I would like to change some grunt task configuration at launch.
And so, I would like to be notified every time a task is run.

For instance, I have often something like that :

```
sass: { // some task
    options: {
        // some options
    },
    android: {
        // android configuration
    },
    ios: {
        // ios configuration
    },
    web: {
        // web configuration
    }
}
```

In my grunt file, I have a section in which I can declare the status of each target (active/inactive), so as to I can build only one, two or three targets. I don't want to build every thing every time.

So when building with grunt  command for instance, I don't want to have to specify manually each target. **I want to detect active ones** and build only that ones. Idem when using plugins like grunt-contrib-watch and declaring tasks execution, I can't declare in advance each target. For now I have 3 targets, but as it is phonegap, I may have 7 tomorrow.

Is there any API or any undocumented event I can use in order to be notified before each run and modify dynamically the scope of the run ?

I see only one solution with the actual grunt state :
- create my on own plugin (n for instance) which will serve as a wrapper for task execution :

```
grunt n:sass will generate grunt sass:ios sass:web if these two targets are actives
```

Any help appreciated.
Thanks.
Best regards.

Comment: How about just adding the `--verbose` parameter to your grunt call? is that sufficient?

Comment: No, I don't want to know what happens, I want to interfere and change the call.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Found a better solution finally.

Instead of creating a task wrapper, I used grunt.util.hooker API to hook grunt.task.run method.
Now I can intercept the call and replace it with mine.

For example, in my case :

```
grunt sass
```

will be intercepted and replaced by

```
grunt sass:web
```